# Lucene 3.6 IndexWriter

Tags: java, lucene

Currently I'm working with Lucene 3.6 and am having difficulty getting IndexWriters to work.

The API documents suggest that:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(Directory, Analyzer);
```

(and a few other similar constructors)is depreciated and that I should use something like:

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(Directory, Configuration);
```

However eclipse won't recognize this newer constructor (lucene-core3.6.jar is added to the build path of my project) and if I use an older constructor I have to suppress a warning (which I don't especially want to do - an exception gets thrown when I index in memory with these older methods).

I've cleaned the project, but the problem still persists.

EDIT: The code I am using:

```
        Directory index = new RAMDirectory();
    StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
    IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_36, analyzer);
    IndexDeletionPolicy IndexDeletionPolicy = new KeepOnlyLastCommitDeletionPolicy();
    MaxFieldLength fieldLength = new MaxFieldLength(256);
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(index, analyzer, false, IndexDeletionPolicy, fieldLength);
    //IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(index, config); 
    writer.setUseCompoundFile(false);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem:

There was a .jar file interfering with lucene (thirdparty-all.jar) which I found through looking at the stack trace. Removing the .jar removed problem.

Answer (score 1):

A good beginning is always reading at the javadoc:

http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/api/all/index.html

Constructors

Constructor and Description

- IndexWriter(Directory d, Analyzer a, boolean create, IndexDeletionPolicy deletionPolicy,
  IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength mfl) Deprecated.  use  IndexWriter(Directory, IndexWriterConfig) instead
- IndexWriter(Directory d, Analyzer a, boolean create,
  IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength mfl) Deprecated.  use
  IndexWriter(Directory, IndexWriterConfig) instead
- IndexWriter(Directory d, Analyzer a, IndexDeletionPolicy
  deletionPolicy, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength mfl) Deprecated.  use
  IndexWriter(Directory, IndexWriterConfig) instead
- IndexWriter(Directory d, Analyzer a, IndexDeletionPolicy
  deletionPolicy, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength mfl, IndexCommit commit)
  Deprecated.  use IndexWriter(Directory, IndexWriterConfig) instead
- IndexWriter(Directory d, Analyzer a, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength mfl)
  Deprecated.  use IndexWriter(Directory, IndexWriterConfig) instead
- **IndexWriter(Directory d, IndexWriterConfig conf) Constructs a new  IndexWriter per the settings given in conf.**

Not suprisingly, you are using a deprecated constructor and Eclipse correctly emit a warning. If you use the last constructor, I am sure Eclipse won't emit a warning.

Comment: No I tried that first. Sorry the first post is in error (edited to reflect that). Eclipse won't compile the source with that constructor, hence the question. Sorry, have been going around in circles.

Comment: This is not possible. It simply means you do not have the right class in the classpath, or that you have multiple version of it. Which error you have when you write new IndexWriter(null,null) ?

Comment: The constructor IndexWriter(String, Analyzer) is ambiguous.

Comment: As I said, you have not the right version in the Classpath. I have shown you an extract from the javadoc and you can read the only constructor with two parameters is the last one. How can Eclipse complain you are using a constructor which does not exist???

Comment: I've downloaded the latest version and added that to the classpath, and the problem still persists. It isn't that.

Comment: You might have several versions on your classpath. Can you put a gist with the copy of the code you are using (Lucene 3.6 constructor? )

Comment: Compilation error is the same as above. I've removed all traces of lucene that aren't 4.0 from the Java build path (Project -> Properties -> Java Build path). When I debug the issue I get thirdparty-all.jar has no source attachement.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13785/discussion-between-edmondo1984-and-tom-kealy)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to change:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
```

to:

```
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);
```

The constructor of StandardAnalyzer takes a Version object. Perhaps Eclipse does not recognize the IndexWriter constructor because there is a compile-time error at an earlier line (i.e. when you try to create a new StandardAnalyzer).

Comment: To whoever down-voted this answer: Could you at least point out what is wrong with this answer? The question states that the code posted has a compile-time error ("eclipse won't recognize this newer constructor" -- I assumed "won't recognize" = error (not just warning)) and asks why the error existed. My answer points out the change needed to eliminate the compile-time error (I did try compiling the code in Eclipse).

Comment: Hi Kai - thanks, I've tried that and it doesn't seem to affect the problem I'm having, but nevertheless is another error in my code.